# How to arrange order of stacked divs backwards?

Tags: html, css

Suppose I have the three divs:

```
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
```

I need the output in the browser to be:
    3
    2
    1

Is there any way to accomplish this without absolute positioning? I tried floats, but it seems you can only reverse it in the horizontal space.

They need to stack VERTICALLY in reverse order.

Comment: For modern browsers you can use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes), specifically the [`order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) rule.

Comment: Would it be too easy to just change the order of the `<div>` elements in the original document?

Comment: have you tried `float: right;`? it will be 3 2 1 then

Comment: @Chanckjh The OP says explicitly *you can only reverse in the horizontal space*. If there is not enough space for all 3 in a row, will the first div go to the second row ?

Comment: For reversing horizontally, you can also use direction:rtl;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do something like this: [**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/up53x/)

Wrap the elements, and rotate both the parent and children elements `180` degrees.

```
#parent, #parent > div {
    transform:rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(180deg);
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Alternatively, this would work too:

```
#parent, #parent > div {
    display:inline-block;
}
#parent > div {
    float:right;
}
```

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/eXZ7B/)

Comment: It's a very good idea, Josh. It must stack vertically, which was not made very clear in my originally question. The transforms would work for this, and I am pretty sure it's the only way to accomplish it. It's not as if we can break the flow vertically (no float up, float down..) The legacy support is pretty poor for transforms though.

Comment: @user1405177 Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/QMP4t/) with vertical stacking then. You would simply remove `inline-block`. And the support isn't *that* bad - http://caniuse.com/transforms2d

Comment: @JoshC I agree the support isn't that bad. The IE support, as usual, is the most worrying. I am 99% positive the only way to make this work is as you suggested with transforms, and for IE, workarounds would surely exist (even if one has to resort to Javascript solutions.)

Comment: The rotation is genius! Float? What's that? You can change vertical flow with a float?? Anyway, I'll check that. I know how to reverse horizontal flow by using "direction" (rtl = right-to-left), but was looking for that trick for vertical flows, for use in a mobile adaptation of a website. Support is not a huge issue, I'm changing the order mostly for cosmetic reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Using float.

http://jsfiddle.net/Q3qTP/1/

```
#example div {float: right;}
```